# I need some help. Why do i get this JavaScript error message and how can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, spring, authentication, null

First of all thank you for your time. I'm really new at programming
so I got this message

```
login.do:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of null
at login_ok (login.do:34)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (login.do:245)
login_ok @ login.do:34
onclick @ login.do:245
```

The problem is that"action" is not working and I have no idea why.
And it is about login. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login_ok(f) {
        f.action = "login_ok.do";
        f.submit();
        if (document.getElementById("log_id").value != document
                .getElementById("hidden1").value) {
            alert("WRONG ID.");
        }
        if (document.getElementById("login_pw").value != document
                .getElementById("hidden2").value) {
            alert("WRONG PASSWORD.");
        }
    }
    function join_go() {
        location.href = "join.do";
    }
    function findidpw_go() {
        location.href = "findidpw.do";
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="LOGIN" onclick="login_ok(this.form)">
```

someone asked me to upload more code
um i don't know how to upload code
so i just put everything in
thank you for understanding

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LOGIN VIEW</title>
<!-- LOGIN css -->
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
    .wrapper { width:100%; height:80%; padding-top:5%; font-family: '돋움';}
    .main { }
    
    .login_box { width:300px; height:350px; padding: 40px; margin: 0 auto;   
                  border: 1px solid black;}
    .login_box .input_login { border-bottom: 2px solid gray; padding: 20px 0 9px 0;}
    .login_box .input_login input { width: 100%; color: gray; font-size: 15px; border:none; font-family:inherit;}
    .login_box .check { color: black; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px; font-family: '돋움';}
    
    .login_box  .login input { width:100%; height:55px;  font-size:16px; 
                               padding:17px 0 16px; border:0; cursor:pointer; font-family:'돋움';}
    
    .login_box .last { width:100%; margin-top:10px; border-top:1px solid gray; padding-top:20px;}
    .login_box .last .join { float:left;}
    .login_box .last .search { float:right;}
    .login_box .last .join a { color: gray;}
    .login_box .last .search a { color:gray;} 
</style>
<!-- LOGIN SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login_ok(f) {
        f.action = "login_ok.do";
        f.submit();
        if (document.getElementById("log_id").value != document
                .getElementById("hidden1").value) {
            alert("WRONG ID.");
        }
        if (document.getElementById("login_pw").value != document
                .getElementById("hidden2").value) {
            alert("WRONG PW.");
        }
    }
    function join_go() {
        location.href = "join.do";
    }
    function findidpw_go() {
        location.href = "findidpw.do";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="../frame/header.jsp" />  
    
    <!-- 로그인창 -->
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="login_box">
                <div class="input_login">
                    <input type="text" name="m_id" placeholder="PUT ID">
                </div>
                <div class="input_login">
                    <input type="password" name="m_pw" placeholder="PUT PW">
                </div>
                <div class="check">
                    <label><input type="checkbox">LOGIN KEEP</label>
                    <input type="hidden" >
                </div>
                <div class="login">
                    <input type="button" value="LOGIN" onclick="login_ok(this.form)">
                </div>
                <div class="last">
                    <input class="join" type="button" value="JOIN" onclick="join_go(this.form)">
                    <input class="search" type="button" value="ID/PW FIND" onclick="findidpw_go(this.form)">
                    <!-- <div class="join"><a href="join_go(this.form)">JOIN</a></div>
                         <div class="search"><a href="findidpw_go(this.form)">ID/PW 찾기</a></div> 
                    -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <jsp:include page="../frame/footer.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question seems to involves Java, Javascript and Struts too. If I'm right, can you add the proper tags?

Comment: I'm guessing that there might be some problem with your `form` tag. Can you post add html( jsp maybe?) code ?

Comment: thank you i guess i'm learning about spring

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a `form` tag in your jsp.